# Serialize child entities of specific content hub entity

Tags: content-hub, serialization

We are exploring Content hub cli. We are able to get content hub entity by ID or definition.

If we get entities by definition, we are getting all the pages with that specific definition using below command-

> dotnet ch-cli serialization pull entity --definition M.Blog

If we get entities by ID, we are getting only that specific page with that ID using below command-

> dotnet ch-cli serialization pull entity --id Portal.Page.BlogPage

We want to have 2 things here-

1. Make content hub entities configurable just like unicorn. And only configured entities will get pulled or pushed.
2. We want to have command to serialize child entities of specified parent entity.

It will be really helpful if someone has any idea on this.

Answer (score 0):

This is not available out of the box with content hub cli. We need to create our custom plugin to achieve this.